# How can I make a syntax match be contained only inside of a specific syntax region without creating separate files?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to have a syntax match (not keyword) match only inside a certain syntax region? I had this issue a while ago and came up with this:

```
" lua.vim
syntax include @loveconf <sfile>:p:h/love-conf.vim
" Some time later
syntax region loveconfregion start="\<love\.conf\>" end="\<end\>"me=e-3,he=e-3,re=e-3 skipwhite skipempty containedin=ALLBUT,luaString,luaComment contains=ALL
highlight loveconf ctermfg=206
```

Where love-conf.vim looked like this:

```
" Simple example; actual file contains a regex
syntax match loveconf "\.window\.width" containedin=loveconfregion
```

I would like, if possible, to move it all to one file. Is there any way to do this?

As a guideline, here is an example file:

```
-- test.lua
t.window.width = 20
-- ^ Not colored

function randomFunction()
    t.window.width = 20
    -- ^ Also not colored
end

function love.conf( t )
    t.window.width = 20
    -- ^ Colored
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and used by most syntax scripts. Here's a short example:

```
#start
match
#end
match

syntax region myRegion start="#start" end="#end" contains=myMatch
syntax match myMatch "match" contained
highlight link myMatch Identifier
```

Your example just misses the `contained` attribute. Because of that, `loveconf` matches anywhere, not just inside the `loveconfregion` (via `containedin=`):

```
syntax match loveconf "\.window\.width" contained containedin=loveconfregion
```

#### syntax include vs. one syntax

The main use case for `:syntax include` is embedding a (sub-)language in another one. Prominent examples are JavaScript inside HTML, or Python inside Vimscript. This avoids duplication and allows to conditionally include stuff (for example, the Vim syntax does not highlight embedded Python if Vim doesn't have support for it).

Another use case is one syntax being an extension of another (for example, Windows Scripting Host is XML). That usually would simply `:runtime! syntax/xml.vim`.

Comment: When I add the `contained` flag to `loveconf`, the first example is covered, but the pattern is still matched within regular functions (see the second example). I would like the syntax match to **only** occur in the third example, where the function is `love.conf`

Comment: That second example syntax group then has `contains=loveconf`. You need to remove that containment there.

Comment: This is the code I have right now: `syntax region loveconfregion start="\<love\.conf\>" end="end" contains=loveconf
syntax match loveconf "\.window\.width" contained
highlight link loveconf Identifier`. With the code `function test() t.window.width end`, `window.width` is highlighted.

Comment: With those 3 commands, I don't see that behavior. Only the text inside `function love.conf( t )` is highlighted, as expected. You probably have other commands that cause this. Especially stuff like `containedin=ALL[BUT]...` can cause this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I the same file and am getting different results: [image](https://i.imgur.com/7RmTFab.png)

Comment: Ah, you define your syntax as an extension of `lua`. That explains the difference; I tested strictly stand-alone. If I `:setf lua` first, I also see the additional highlighting.

Comment: And there we have the culprit: `luaFunctionBlock ... contains=ALLBUT,....` This needs to exclude the `loveconf` syntax group. Unfortunately, the lua syntax does not provide any extension (syntax cluster) for that, so it needs to be overwritten:

Comment: `syn clear luaFunctionBlock` and then `syn region luaFunctionBlock matchgroup=luaFunction start=/\<function\>/ end=/\<end\>/  transparent contains=ALLBUT,luaTodo,luaSpecial,luaElseifThen,luaElse,luaThenEnd,luaIn,loveconf`

Comment: That works very well, thanks! Now, would it be possible to get this to work for the multiple versions of function definitions? See this [this](https://i.imgur.com/NwCwnPH.png) for what I mean. See how the `loveconfregion` syntax region (highlighted red) extends beyond the function definition because `luaFunctionBlock` takes the last `end`? I've tried using `keepend` but that was **too** greedy

Comment: Please submit that separate issue as a new question, so people can copy-and-paste the reproducible example. In general, extending an existing syntax is very hard, and sometimes you run into roadblocks like these; especially if the original syntax wasn't made with extensibility in mind.